# Scaling image size like snapchat filter images in android application

Tags: android, image, multi-touch, snapchat

I m trying to make on simple image filter like snapchat does in my android application. 
As you can see in below image 
[image: Image of filter]

Here you can see  the image in red rounded circle. On touching the image and draging with two fingers (like pinching) it changes its size as well as orientation and can be draged to any where on the screen.

Im looking for the same implementation in my android app but not able to get the exact solution as snapchat does.

Please provide solution to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mean **pinch to zoom**?

Comment: yeah some what kind of that functionality but it should increase the size of image and when i trie that pinch zoom the image expands in its own area rather than expanding to the full screen or area of the device display- @skydroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo project helped me get the same functionality I was looking for.

[ImageGesture](https://github.com/techierishi/ImageGesture) - Zoom,scale and move the image.

Answer (score 1):

For this functionality i suggest you to use [**PhotoView**](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).

it provide following functions

- Out of the box zooming, using multi-touch and double-tap. Scrolling,
- with smooth scrolling fling.
- Works perfectly when used in a scrolling parent (such as ViewPager).
- Allows the application to be notified
  when the displayed Matrix has changed. Useful for when you need to
  update your UI based on the current zoom/scroll position.
- Allows the application to be notified when the user taps on the Photo.

**Usage**

```
Build.gradle

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
}
```

**XML**

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```